# In Oracle 11g how do you time weight average data hourly between two dates?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I have replaced my original question with this final answer. With the help from Mr. MTO and Mr. Ponder Stibbons and four months of playing around with my oracle 11G instance, I finally have what you see here. This query is Designed for SCADA systems primarily and will do the following...

This query will perform a Time Weighted Average hourly between two date times as TWA, Minimum and Maximum Values during that Interval as Vmin and Vmax. It will also return Time of Minimum and Time of Maximum as Hmin and Hmax. (These are the date times of the minimum value occurrence and maximum value occurrence ).Starting and Ending Interval values as VSTART and VEND. This query will not fail on daylight savings in March or August. (This is why I am using TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ)

Note: this query is setup for 1 hour intervals and any desired interval is possible by replacing and adding just a few items. So Enjoy!!!

This Query works in my Oracle 11g instance and after writing this post i copy-ed the exact text below and pasted into my SQL Developer. So it works!!
I am having trouble running this in sqlfiddle but soon i will figure this out and have a running test for you.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b2838/23)

```
 -- Lets Begin the Query
 WITH INPUTS AS ( 
    SELECT RECNM, 
          TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ ( '01-JAN-15 00:00:00 AMERICA/LOS_ANGELES','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS TZR' ) AS START_TIME,
          TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ ( '06-NOV-15 23:59:59 AMERICA/LOS_ANGELES','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS TZR' ) AS END_TIME
    FROM POINTS
  WHERE ACRONYM = 'WELL32-PSI'  
) ,
ALL_INTERVALS AS ( 
    SELECT RECNM,
         START_TIME + NUMTODSINTERVAL ( ( LEVEL-1 ) , 'HOUR' ) AS TIME
    FROM INPUTS
    CONNECT BY
    LEVEL-1 <=
               EXTRACT ( DAY FROM END_TIME - START_TIME ) * 24 +
               EXTRACT ( HOUR FROM END_TIME - START_TIME ) 
) ,
ALL_TIMES AS ( 
    SELECT 
       TIME, 
       VALUE, 
       1 AS HAS_VALUE
    FROM HST H
    INNER JOIN INPUTS I
        ON ( H.RECNM = I.RECNM
        AND H.TIME BETWEEN CAST ( I.START_TIME AS TIMESTAMP ) 
        AND  CAST ( I.END_TIME AS TIMESTAMP ) ) 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
       TIME, 
       NULL, 
       0
    FROM ALL_INTERVALS
    ORDER BY TIME,1, 2 NULLS FIRST 
) ,
LEAD_LAG_TIMES AS ( 
    SELECT 
         TIME,
         LAST_VALUE ( VALUE IGNORE NULLS ) OVER ( ORDER BY TIME ASC, VALUE ASC ) AS VALUE,
         24 * 60 * 60 * EXTRACT ( DAY FROM LEAD ( TIME ) OVER ( ORDER BY TIME ASC,VALUE ASC ) -TIME ) +
              60 * 60 * EXTRACT ( HOUR FROM LEAD ( TIME ) OVER ( ORDER BY TIME ASC,VALUE ASC ) -TIME ) +
                   60 * EXTRACT ( MINUTE FROM LEAD ( TIME ) OVER ( ORDER BY TIME ASC,VALUE ASC ) -TIME ) + 
                        EXTRACT ( SECOND FROM LEAD ( TIME ) OVER ( ORDER BY TIME ASC,VALUE ASC ) -TIME ) AS DURATION
    FROM ALL_TIMES 
) 
SELECT CAST ( TRUNC ( TIME,'HH24' ) AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE ) AS TIME,
    SUM ( VALUE * DURATION ) / SUM ( DURATION ) AS TWA,
    MIN ( VALUE ) AS VMIN, 
    MAX ( TIME ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY VALUE DESC ) AS TMIN,
    MAX ( VALUE ) AS VMAX, 
    MAX ( TIME ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY VALUE ASC ) AS TMAX,
    SUM ( VALUE ) AS TOTAL,
    MAX ( VALUE ) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY TIME ASC) as VSTART,
    MAX ( VALUE ) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY TIME ASC) as VEND,
    SUM ( DURATION ) AS TOTAL_DURATION 
FROM LEAD_LAG_TIMES
GROUP BY CAST ( TRUNC ( TIME,'HH24' ) AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE ) 
ORDER BY TIME ASC
```

EDIT: You can Include this in the final select statement for a 1 hour Rolling Average that is Time Weighted! I find this very useful in the waste water industry as state regulations/reporting require 24 hour rolling averages and 72 minute rolling averages. If you need a 24 rolling average change ROWS 1 PROCECDING to ROWS 24 PROCEDING

```
ROUND( AVG ( SUM ( value * DURATION ) / sum ( DURATION ) ) OVER (ORDER BY CAST ( TRUNC ( TIME,'hh24' ) AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE ), CAST ( TRUNC ( TIME,'hh24' ) AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE ) ROWS 1 PRECEDING),2) AS ROLLING_1H_VAVG,
```

Standard deviation is fun, so add this as well.

```
ROUND( STDDEV ( VALUE ) , 2 ) as VDEV,
```

If you need the value prior to your start time and after your stop time you can place this with the other union all's.

```
UNION ALL
SELECT
   MAX(H.TIME) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY H.TIME DESC) AS TIME, 
   MAX(H.VALUE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY H.TIME DESC),
   1
FROM INPUTS I
INNER JOIN HST H
    ON H.TIME < I.START_TIME
UNION ALL
SELECT
   MIN(H.TIME) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY H.TIME) AS TIME, 
   MIN(H.VALUE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY H.TIME),
   1
FROM INPUTS I
INNER JOIN HST H
    ON H.TIME > I.END_TIME
```

Comment: My database version is: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.1.0.7.0 - Production. I also forgot to add that this is my first post!   Cheers!

Comment: On my simple average that i calculated in excel 12:00:01 should be 12:01:00 and so on for the other three.

Comment: Since you have fractional seconds, your where conditions should better be `to_timestamp('01/01/2015:00:00:00','mm/dd/YYYY:HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_TIMESTAMP('01/01/2015:23:59:59.999999999','mm/dd/YYYY:HH24:MI:SSxff')`

Comment: How did you calculate weight for row in 'time weighted averages per minute' example?

Comment: Thanks Wernfried, I will change that. KSA you can compute a time weighted average by sum(time*value)/sum(time) I did this in excell for every minute by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your sample data - it didn't have a full hour's data so I've done a weighted average per minute.

You haven't specified what you want to do at the boundaries so I've taken the weighted average of the immediately preceding and succeeding values.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/05649e/4)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST ( Acronym, Date_Time, Value ) AS
          SELECT '32-PRESS', TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:00:07.120000000', 63.7363 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '32-PRESS', TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:00:17.088000000', 64.5604 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '32-PRESS', TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:00:27.864000000', 66.3004 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '32-PRESS', TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:00:45.080000000', 66.804 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '32-PRESS', TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:00:55.056000000', 67.4908 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '32-PRESS', TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:01:11.384000000', 66.9872 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '32-PRESS', TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:01:30.424000000', 67.4451 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '32-PRESS', TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:01:40.408000000', 67.9487 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '32-PRESS', TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:01:50.408000000', 68.6813 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '32-PRESS', TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:02:01.304000000', 68.1777 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '32-PRESS', TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:02:11.304000000', 67.1245 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '32-PRESS', TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:02:21.264000000', 66.5293 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '32-PRESS', TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:02:31.232000000', 65.4762 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '32-PRESS', TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:02:45.736000000', 65.0183 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '32-PRESS', TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:02:59.312000000', 64.5604 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '32-PRESS', TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:03:14.712000000', 64.1026 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH temp AS (
  SELECT  ACRONYM,
          DATE_TIME,
          VALUE
  FROM    TEST
  UNION
  SELECT  ACRONYM,
          TO_TIMESTAMP( TO_CHAR( DATE_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI' ), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI' ),
          NULL
  FROM    TEST
  GROUP BY
          ACRONYM,
          TO_TIMESTAMP( TO_CHAR( DATE_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI' ), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI' )
  UNION
  SELECT  ACRONYM,
          TO_TIMESTAMP( TO_CHAR( DATE_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI' ), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI' ) + INTERVAL '1' MINUTE,
          NULL
  FROM    TEST
  GROUP BY
          ACRONYM,
          TO_TIMESTAMP( TO_CHAR( DATE_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI' ), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI' )
  ORDER BY
          1,2
),
temp2 AS (
  SELECT  ACRONYM,
          DATE_TIME,
          COALESCE(
            VALUE,
            COALESCE(
              LAG( VALUE ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ACRONYM ORDER BY DATE_TIME ),
              LEAD( VALUE ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ACRONYM ORDER BY DATE_TIME )
            )
            +
            (
              COALESCE(
                LEAD( VALUE ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ACRONYM ORDER BY DATE_TIME ),
                LAG( VALUE ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ACRONYM ORDER BY DATE_TIME )
              )
              -
              COALESCE(
                LAG( VALUE ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ACRONYM ORDER BY DATE_TIME ),
                LEAD( VALUE ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ACRONYM ORDER BY DATE_TIME )
              )
            )
            *
            EXTRACT( SECOND FROM ( DATE_TIME - LAG( DATE_TIME, 1, DATE_TIME ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ACRONYM ORDER BY DATE_TIME ) ) )
            /
            EXTRACT( SECOND FROM (
              LEAD( DATE_TIME, 1, DATE_TIME ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ACRONYM ORDER BY DATE_TIME )
              -
              LAG( DATE_TIME, 1, DATE_TIME ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ACRONYM ORDER BY DATE_TIME )
            ) )
          ) AS VALUE,
          LEAD( DATE_TIME ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ACRONYM ORDER BY DATE_TIME ) AS NEXT_DATE_TIME
  FROM    temp
)
SELECT  ACRONYM,
        TO_DATE( TO_CHAR( DATE_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI' ), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI' ) AS DATE_TIME,
        SUM( VALUE * EXTRACT( SECOND FROM ( NEXT_DATE_TIME - DATE_TIME ) ) ) / 60 AS VALUE
FROM    temp2
WHERE   NEXT_DATE_TIME IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
        ACRONYM,
        TO_DATE( TO_CHAR( DATE_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI' ), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI' )
ORDER BY
        1,2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/05649e/4/0)**:

```
|  ACRONYM |                 DATE_TIME |             VALUE |
|----------|---------------------------|-------------------|
| 32-PRESS | January, 01 0015 00:00:00 | 65.43946117333333 |
| 32-PRESS | January, 01 0015 00:01:00 | 67.56109262835211 |
| 32-PRESS | January, 01 0015 00:02:00 | 66.32093658633383 |
| 32-PRESS | January, 01 0015 00:03:00 | 64.20983764043636 |
```

**EDIT**

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1fa17/39)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE POINTS ( RECNM NUMBER, ACRONYM VARCHAR2(20) );
INSERT INTO POINTS  VALUES(1136, '32-PRESS');
INSERT INTO POINTS  VALUES(1138, 'OTHER_POINT');

CREATE TABLE HST ( RECNM NUMBER, TIME TIMESTAMP, VALUE NUMBER );
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:00:00',63.3);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1138, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:00:00',0.0);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:00:07',63.7);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:00:17',64.6);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:00:28',66.3);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:00:45',66.8);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:00:55',67.5);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:01:11',67.0);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:01:30',67.4);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:01:40',67.9);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:01:50',68.7);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:02:01',68.2);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:02:11',67.1);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:02:21',66.5);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:02:31',65.5);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:02:46',65.0);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:02:59',64.6);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:03:15',64.1);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:03:25',63.2);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:03:35',62.7);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:04:05',62.2);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:04:32',61.8);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:05:40',61.3);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:05:55',60.8);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:10:20',60.3);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:10:38',60.9);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:10:48',61.3);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:10:58',61.8);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:11:27',62.3);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:13:54',61.8);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:14:10',61.4);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:14:41',60.9);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:15:18',61.4);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:15:51',60.9);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:16:19',60.4);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:16:32',59.9);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:17:04',59.4);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:17:27',59.9);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:17:37',59.4);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:17:58',59.0);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:18:22',59.4);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:18:50',59.9);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:19:00',60.3);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:19:25',60.8);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:19:34',61.4);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:19:45',62.1);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:19:55',62.5);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:20:30',63.0);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:20:51',63.5);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:21:03',63.9);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:22:04',64.4);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:22:28',64.8);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:23:17',64.4);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:23:27',63.9);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:24:31',63.4);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:26:06',63.0);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:27:20',62.5);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:27:30',61.9);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:28:08',62.4);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:28:37',62.0);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:29:21',62.5);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:29:38',62.9);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:31:27',62.5);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:32:01',62.0);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:32:25',62.5);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:35:07',62.9);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:35:56',62.5);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:36:06',62.0);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:36:59',61.5);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:39:31',62.0);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:40:12',61.5);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:40:22',60.9);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:40:35',60.5);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:40:55',60.0);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:41:22',60.5);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:41:46',60.1);
INSERT INTO HST  VALUES(1136, TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:42:31',60.6);
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH inputs AS (
  SELECT RECNM,
         TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:00:00' AS start_time,
         TIMESTAMP '15-01-01 00:40:00' AS end_time
  FROM   POINTS
  WHERE  ACRONYM = '32-PRESS'
),
all_minutes AS (
  SELECT RECNM,
         start_time + (LEVEL-1)/24/60 AS time
  FROM   inputs
  CONNECT BY
         LEVEL - 1 <= EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM end_time - start_time )
),
all_times AS (
  SELECT  TIME,
          VALUE,
          1 AS HAS_VALUE
  FROM    HST h
          INNER JOIN inputs i
          ON (     h.RECNM = i.RECNM
               AND h.TIME BETWEEN i.start_time
                          AND     i.end_time )
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  TIME,
          NULL,
          0
  FROM    all_minutes
  ORDER BY 1, 2 NULLS FIRST
),
lag_lead_ignore_nulls AS (
  SELECT TIME,
         VALUE,
         COUNT( VALUE ) OVER ( ORDER BY TIME ASC, VALUE ASC NULLS FIRST ) AS LAG_GRP,
         COUNT( VALUE ) OVER ( ORDER BY TIME DESC, VALUE DESC NULLS LAST ) AS LEAD_GRP
  FROM   all_times
),
lag_lead_values AS (
  SELECT  TIME,
          VALUE,
          FIRST_VALUE( TIME  ) OVER ( PARTITION BY LAG_GRP  ORDER BY VALUE ASC NULLS LAST ) AS PREV_MEASURED_TIME,
          FIRST_VALUE( VALUE ) OVER ( PARTITION BY LAG_GRP  ORDER BY VALUE ASC NULLS LAST ) AS PREV_MEASURED_VALUE,
          FIRST_VALUE( TIME  ) OVER ( PARTITION BY LEAD_GRP ORDER BY VALUE ASC NULLS LAST ) AS NEXT_MEASURED_TIME,
          FIRST_VALUE( VALUE ) OVER ( PARTITION BY LEAD_GRP ORDER BY VALUE ASC NULLS LAST ) AS NEXT_MEASURED_VALUE,
          LEAD( TIME ) OVER ( ORDER BY TIME ASC ) AS NEXT_TIME
  FROM    lag_lead_ignore_nulls
),
interpolated_values AS (
  SELECT CAST( TIME AS DATE ) TIME,
         COALESCE(
           VALUE,
           PREV_MEASURED_VALUE
           + ( NEXT_MEASURED_VALUE - PREV_MEASURED_VALUE )
           * (
               60 * EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM TIME - PREV_MEASURED_TIME )
               + EXTRACT( SECOND FROM TIME - PREV_MEASURED_TIME )
             )
           / (
               60 * EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM NEXT_MEASURED_TIME - PREV_MEASURED_TIME )
               + EXTRACT( SECOND FROM NEXT_MEASURED_TIME - PREV_MEASURED_TIME )
             )
         ) AS INTERPOLATED_VALUE,
         60 * EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM NEXT_TIME - TIME )
         + EXTRACT( SECOND FROM NEXT_TIME - TIME ) AS DURATION
  FROM lag_lead_values
)
SELECT TRUNC( TIME, 'MI' ) AS TIME,
       SUM( INTERPOLATED_VALUE * DURATION ) / SUM( DURATION ) AS TWA,
       SUM( DURATION ) AS TOTAL_DURATION
FROM   interpolated_values
WHERE  INTERPOLATED_VALUE IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY TRUNC( TIME, 'MI' )
ORDER BY TIME ASC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1fa17/39/0)**:

```
|                      TIME |                TWA | TOTAL_DURATION |
|---------------------------|--------------------|----------------|
| January, 01 0015 00:00:00 |  65.38833333333333 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:01:00 |  67.56302083333334 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:02:00 |  66.30575757575758 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:03:00 |  63.48385416666667 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:04:00 |  62.02027777777778 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:05:00 |  61.45441176470588 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:06:00 |  60.79056603773585 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:07:00 | 60.677358490566036 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:08:00 |  60.56415094339623 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:09:00 | 60.450943396226414 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:10:00 |  60.62924528301887 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:11:00 |  62.09051724137931 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:12:00 |  62.18775510204082 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:13:00 |  61.96530612244898 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:14:00 |  61.28333333333333 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:15:00 | 61.252027027027026 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:16:00 |  60.27410714285714 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:17:00 |  59.47416666666667 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:18:00 |  59.34888888888889 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:19:00 |              61.06 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:20:00 |  62.86071428571429 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:21:00 |             63.895 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:22:00 |  64.61114754098361 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:23:00 |  64.16431972789115 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:24:00 |  63.52513020833333 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:25:00 |  63.27789473684211 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:26:00 | 63.002526315789474 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:27:00 | 62.245045045045046 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:28:00 |  62.23263157894737 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:29:00 |  62.56314393939394 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:30:00 |  62.81926605504587 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:31:00 | 62.544587155963306 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:32:00 |  62.29191176470588 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:33:00 |  62.58641975308642 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:34:00 |  62.73456790123457 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:35:00 |  62.87131687242798 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:36:00 |  62.02166666666667 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:37:00 |  61.50328947368421 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:38:00 |  61.70065789473684 |             60 |
| January, 01 0015 00:39:00 |  61.94731359649123 |             60 |
```

Comment: Thanks MTO for your help!! Much appreciated!!!! How can edit lead and lag as you can not use them in oracle 11.1g? i Irecently have been reading up on the differences between 11.1 and 11.2.

Comment: [`LAG`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions075.htm) and [`LEAD`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions079.htm#i83834) are available in Oracle 11.1 - I've linked to the documentation for that version. The only difference from 11.1 and 11.2 is that in [11.2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions082.htm) you can use `RESPECT NULLS` and `IGNORE NULLS` but that isn't needed here.

Comment: Hi MTO, Hope all is well! I have been playing with your query almost all night trying to figure out how to fill in data for missing minutes, hours, days, and even weeks. Sometimes it skips the missing minutes and sometimes outputs zeros in its place but it runs super fast!!!! any pointers? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5850c/3    I can not seem to get an output from fiddle but in runs in sqlplus on my database very well.

Comment: @ID10T_ERROR Added edit to perform linear interpolation to fill in values for multiple missing minutes. I think it will work on 11.1 (but can't test it). If you are running on 11.2 then it can be rewritten in a much simpler format using `LAG( ... IGNORE NULLS ) OVER (...)` but from your previous comment, I don't think you are so I did it the more complicated (and backwards compatible) way.

Answer (score 1):

This query generated desired values:

```
with input as (
  select value, htime, to_char(htime, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') mnt,
      extract(day from d)+extract(hour from d)/24+
      extract(minute from d)/(24*60)+extract (second from d)/(24*60*60) tm
    from (select value, htime, htime-timestamp '1899-12-30 00:00:00' d from test))
select distinct mnt, round(
    sum(tm*value) over (partition by mnt)/sum(tm) over (partition by mnt), 6) wav
  from input order by mnt
```

Output:

```
MNT               WAV
----------------  ----------
2015-01-01 12:00   65.77838
2015-01-01 12:01   67.765575
2015-01-01 12:02   66.147733
2015-01-01 12:03   64.1026
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0eec2/2)</sup>

According to [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214094) Excel calendar starts with '1900-01-01', 
but I had to modify this date slightly to achieve "date zero" to get number values for time difference exactly like in spreadsheet. 
Rest is only the matter of substracting timestamps, casting this difference to number and summing results for each minute with function `sum()` in  analytic version.

If you have gaps in data you need at first create periods for each minute with recursive query (`connect by`) and then left join this query with mine filling data for gaps with function `lag(wav ignore nulls)` gathering weighted average from previous minute(s).

---

Edit: Version filling gaps:

```
with input as (
    select value, htime, to_char(htime, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') mnt,
        extract(day from d)+extract(hour from d)/24+
        extract(minute from d)/(24*60)+extract (second from d)/(24*60*60) tm
      from (select value, htime, htime-timestamp '1899-12-30 00:00:00' d from data)),
  period as (select to_date(min(mnt), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') m1, 
                    to_date(max(mnt), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') m2 from input),
  minutes as (
    select to_char(to_date(m1) + (level - 1)/(24*60), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') mnt
      from period connect by level+1<(m2-m1)*24*60),
  calc as (
    select distinct mnt, 
        round(sum(tm*value) over (partition by mnt)/sum(tm) over (partition by mnt), 6) wav
      from minutes left join input using (mnt) order by mnt)
select mnt, wav, nvl(wav, lag(wav ignore nulls) over (order by mnt)) wavg from calc
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1481b/1)</sup>

Subquery `input` *prepares* data for further treatment, `period` selects min and max minute from table 
(you can insert some values by hand here instead of querying from table, for example "date '2015-01-01 13:52:00'"),
`minutes` generates... minutes recursively for given period, `calc` counts weighted averages joining input and minutes,
last select fills last known averages for *empty* minutes - you can observe it for minutes 6, 7, 12 in SQLFiddle.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8c3fe/1      Thanks Ponder Stibbons! I am getting very close to what i am looking for!! I have added more data to your Fidder query and you where right about the "gaps" i will need to edit this statement to carry over the previous value though the missing minute's

Comment: OK, I'll look at this. Is column `acronym` important - should weighted average be calculated separately for each acronym?

Comment: acronym and the recnm is the devices name. acronym is a memonic and recnm is an actual record number. they are static. 1136 means 32-PRESS. If i wanted to select a particular device i would say "where points.recnm=1136" or "where points.acronym like '32-PRESS' as they are the same. Table HST does not have the acronym saved in it. Tt was just easy to use as example. HST only has hst.recnm.

Comment: I am going to look at this later at work and make versions so I can time weight average by second, (minute is done, thanyou btw), hour, days, and then years. I have a lot of data for many years on my system. Its going to be fun to play around with this. :-)

Comment: Good luck. I wanted to be Jedi, but they said I have to little midi-chlorians :/

Comment: Mr. Ponder Stibbons, Two real quick questions. I have to add a where statement to only select data from '1136' 'The acronym' if i use your statement ill select all the records from my table. just for a drill i put your statement in Oracle SQL Developer and in sqlplus and i receive an error. "ERROR at line 15:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis" i am running Oracle Database 11g Release 11.1.0.7.0 - Production. I notice some problems in the past  because fiddle is 11gR2. The error is right at the last line at IGNORE NULLS, the I in IGNORE to be exact.

Comment: **1)** add `where acronym='1136'` in line 5  **2)** use `last_value` instead of `lag`, it seems that 'ignore nulls' was added later. 
I just tested last_value() on Oracle10g and worked fine. [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1481b/3).

Comment: Thanks Again Ponder Stibbons! I got it to work perfectly, The returned query from my obdc oracle 11g matches my scada data perfectly. I was able to do it by seconds as well by just tweaking the above.

Comment: Congratulations :-) Please consider upvoting second answer given by user @MT0, he put much effort/time trying to help you.

Comment: I am too new to up vote :(......I am currently working on adding an "as hour" with "as minute", with "as second". The larger the data sample between dates combined  with  larger intervals my time weighted average strays 3psi from an actual TWA. I believe i have the flow of the recursive call down.

Comment: The connect by level runs out of memory if the time between dates is very large. Is there a way to get around using connect by level?

Comment: Never experienced such error, probably data generated by recursive query is very big. Try reduce period boundaries if possible, maybe you find 
[this link](http://blog.tanelpoder.com/2008/06/08/generating-lots-of-rows-using-connect-by-safely/) helpful.