# Fill the Gap of missing data in table with smooth average using oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
CREATE TABLE T(ID NUMBER, X NUMBER, Y NUMBER);
INSERT INTO T(ID,X) VALUES(1,10);
INSERT INTO T(ID) VALUES(2);
INSERT INTO T(ID,X) VALUES(3,33);
INSERT INTO T(ID,X) VALUES(4,20);
INSERT INTO T(ID) VALUES(5);
INSERT INTO T(ID) VALUES(6);
INSERT INTO T(ID) VALUES(7);
INSERT INTO T(ID,X) VALUES(8,11);
INSERT INTO T(ID) VALUES(9);
INSERT INTO T(ID) VALUES(10);
INSERT INTO T(ID,X) VALUES(11,10);
```

Current Table:

```
ID      X       Y
---------------------------
1       10  
2               
3       33  
4       20  
5               
6               
7               
8       11  
9               
10              
11      10
```

Desired Output:

```
ID      X       Y
---------------------------
1       10  
2               21.5
3       33  
4       20  
5               17.75
6               15.5
7               13.25
8       11  
9               10.67
10              10.34
11      10
```

In the above table there are missing values for column-x. 
I want to fill the missing values in column x using some mathematical calculation

row_count= no of rows with null value in x between interval (x1,x2)
step = (x2-x1)/(row_count+1)

nextRowValue for column-x = PrevRowValue +/- step

I have filled the missing column-x value in column-Y using the above calculation.    e.g.

```
(x1,x2)=(11,20)
row_count=row with id (5,6,7) = 3
step=(20-11)/(3+1)=2.25
we get 3 missing value for id (5,6,7) as
20-2.25=17.75
17.75-2.25=15.5
15.5-2.25=13.25
```

I have asked a similar question where the interval was fixed to 60 on stackoverflow  below link
[How to spread the average between two intervals in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31541384/how-to-spread-the-average-between-two-intervals-in-oracle)

In this question however the length of interval is not fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is just a walloping expression with a bunch of analytic functions.

You can identify groups for a given x followed by nulls by just doing a cumulative count of the valid x values.  With the group, the minimum (or maximum) value of x in this group is the first value.

The number of values is given by using `count(*) over`.  And you can use `row_number()` to enumerate them.  Getting the next value is a bit of a trick.  This query uses `lead( ignore nulls)`, which requires Oracle 11+.

The rest is just arithmetic.  If I have this correct, then it is:

```
select t.*,
       ( (row_number() over (partition by xgrp order by id) - 1) /
         count(*) over (partition by xgrp)
       ) *
       (next_x - min(x) over (partition by xgrp)) +
       min(x) over (partition by xgrp)
from (select t.*, count(x) over (order by id) as xgrp,
             lead(x ignore nulls) over (order by id) as next_x
      from t
     ) t;
```

You need additional logic to ignore a value when there is already an x value `(case when x is null then . . . end)`.  I'm not including that because I think it just complicates the important part of the expression.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, For providing the solution so quickly. It really help me.